# rspec fails with 'undefined method `be_include' for Class'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

```
# /spec/presenters/pdf_download_spec.rb

  describe "instance methods" do
    let(:survey) { Survey.create :title => "test survey" }
    let(:pdf_download) { PdfDownload.new survey }
    before do
      # only write to tmp folders
      PdfDownload.any_instance.stub(:location_prefix) { '../tmp' }
    end

    it "should stub location prefix properly" do
      pdf_download.system_path.should_not be_empty
      pdf_download.system_path.should be_include File.join(Rails.root, 'tmp')
      pdf_download.system_path.should be_start_with File.join(Rails.root, 'tmp')
    end
  end

# app/models/pdf_download.rb

  def system_path
    File.expand_path File.join Rails.root, "public", location_path
  end
```

The failure message:

```
  1) PdfDownload instance methods should stub location prefix properly
     Failure/Error: expect(pdf_download.system_path).to be_empty
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `be_empty' for #<#<Class:0x007f8af0924870>:0x007f8af1b82a08>
     # ./spec/presenters/pdf_download_spec.rb:36:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Why doesn't rspec recognize `be_include` or `be_start_with` as valid methods as described [here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-0/docs/matchers/predicate-matchers)? It might be something obvious, in which case I apologize. I have rspec 2.12.2. Thanks!

Update: I realized in rspec-expectations 2.12, start_with and include are built-in matchers, so I don't need to (indeed I can't) prefix them with `be_` anymore. That solves 2 of the 3 failures above. But I still get a failure with `should_not be_empty`, which according to the docs [should still work](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-12/docs/built-in-matchers/predicate-matchers!).

Comment: @sawa please see edit above.

Comment: If you vote to close this question, please explain how I can improve it. I have added clarification and updated my progress.

Answer (score 0):

`be_include` is not a matcher or finder. I think, you want to check, if your file path is correct or not, Do this :

```
pdf_download.system_path.should eql(File.join(Rails.root, 'tmp'))
```

you can use include like this, but I dont think it will work. You should do this :-

```
pdf_download.system_path.should include File.join(Rails.root, 'tmp')
```

or

Thanks

Comment: `be_include` should be a custom matcher as described [here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-0/docs/matchers/predicate-matchers). It's possible that feature has been phased out in my rspec version though. Still investigating.